# IntelliJ space added after comment starting with /** in scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, code-formatting, scaladoc

In IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3 the comment code is formatted like this:

```
/** ***********************/
/* BACKEND CONFIGURATION */
/** ***********************/
```

Notice the space after /**

Is it possible to remove that space?

= UPDATE =

To be more precise, I am using these comments solely **in-line** to (same as I did in java) mark important blocks if algorithm is lengthy.

I just have tested this

```
/************************
  * Test text
  * @param jobConfig
  */
class AutoencoderTrainingJob(val jobConfig: Sometype
```

scaladoc is **being displayed** by IntelliJ *Quick Documentation*. The additional asterisks just show up as part of class descirption

Comment: Note that Scala distinguishes between `/*` and `/**`. The latter indicates that you want scala-docs generated. Using an entire line full of asterisks is not a style I have come across...

Comment: I do realise that, but same is true for javadoc and, if I recall correctly, for instance eclipse does not add space for comments like this  /*********/ in Java. Since I have seen this behavior in eclipse I assumed it should be possible to configure idea the same way.

Comment: It is a reasonable demand. Do you know if Scaladoc actually works with this?